# Ionic: this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state is undifined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

i asking again for your programming supports.

Let me explain, my problems and my context.
In ionic, i have to make a tabs mobile application that first ask you to write a login/password to connect.
When the user click on the connexion button, it will first verify if the login/password are correct then send the login/password data to the tabs components that's will send a request with the login/password data to get the articles of the login and password of the user.

There are two things that you need to know:

1. my login page is a modal that is created by the tabs components
2. I use the NavigationExtras / Extra State to send data to another page but i do this only when the user click on the button so there are nothing in the constructor of the modal page

So in result, after it create the modal nn tabs, i am waiting for the data from router.navigate only when the button in modals is clicked, sadly the tabs constructor won't wait the button to be clicked so i ended to have this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state as undifined in tabs

How to prevent this and make tabs components wait the modals page button to be clicked to send the data needed?

Here are the code:

tabs.page.ts

```
    export class TabsPage {

  donnee_article: any;
  login: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,public modalController: ModalController,private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) 
  {
    console.log("create modal");
    this.presentModal(); // on affiche le modal

    if (this.reponse_connexion(this.login,this.password) == true)
    {
      this.http.get('http://www.sebastien-thon.fr/cours/M4104Cip/projet/index.php?login='+this.login+'&mdp='+this.password).subscribe((data) => 
      {
        this.donnee_article = data;
        console.log(this.donnee_article);
      }); 
    }
    console.log(this.login);
    console.log(this.password);

  }

  reponse_connexion(login, password)
  {
    console.log("router " + this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
    {
      this.login = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.login_classe;
      this.password = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.password_classe;

      if (typeof this.login != "undefined" && this.password != undefined)
      {
        console.log("true");
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("false");
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
  async presentModal() 
  {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ConnexionPage
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

connexion.page.ts

```
export class ConnexionPage implements OnInit {

  requete: any; // varaible stockée la réponse du serveur
  login  : string; // représente le login du premier input 
  password: string; // représente le mot de passe du deuxième input
  message_warning: string; // représente la boite de message en cas de réponse de la requête

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private modalCtrl:ModalController, public alertController: AlertController, public router: Router) 
  {

  }

  Connexion_classe()
  {
    console.log(this.login);
    console.log(this.password);
    this.http.get('http://www.sebastien-thon.fr/cours/M4104Cip/projet/index.php?connexion&login='+this.login+'&mdp='+this.password)
    .subscribe((data) => 
    {
      this.requete = data;
      if (this.requete.erreur === "Login ou mot de passe incorrect") // si la reponse du serveur donne une erreur
      {
        this.message_warning = this.requete.erreur; // le message_warning devient le message d'erreur
        this.presentAlert(); // on active la fonction pour mettre l'alerte
        this.login = ""; // on remet le champ login vide
        this.password = ""; // on remet le champ password vide
      }
      else // sinon si la reponse du serveur est bonne cad on a marqué un login et password correcte alors:
      {
        // on envoie le login et password aux tabs pour qu'ils recupérent la liste d'article avec notre login et password
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state:
          {
            login_classe: this.login,
            password_classe: this.password
          }
        }
        this.router.navigate(['tabs'], navigationExtras);
        console.log("bye modal");
        this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    });

  }

  async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Connexion échouée',
      subHeader: 'Erreur:',
      message: this.message_warning,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

thanks in advance, i am waiting for yours responses

Answer (score 0):

modalController is not sending data in state. So you need to wait till long your modalController returned the data.

```
 async presentModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: ConnexionPage
  });
 await modal.present();

const datafromModal = await modal.onDidDismiss();  // wait till modal not returned the data

//then call here function
 if (this.reponse_connexion(this.login,this.password) == true){
 // logic part
}
```

And need to pass data in modal dismiss instead of router state

```
 let data = { 'foo': 'bar' };
 this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
```

and will be accessible in tab page in datafromModal variable

Comment: i have made your code with async and await but it seen that tabs don't wait and directly go console.log();

Comment: constructor won't have other function then  presentModal(); All constructor code goes inside presentModal

Comment: I got a:  Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null error why?